# Why does NetworkInformation.effectiveType return me a 4g network instead of wifi?

Tags: javascript

I am using [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) to get the network type.

```js
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

// output in Microsoft edge browser console
// {onchange: null, effectiveType: "4g", rtt: 100, downlink: 1.5, saveData: false}
```

I am using the company's wifi network. I expect the value of `effectiveType` property should be `wifi`. Because I have some code logic like this:

```
if(effectiveType === 'wifi') {
  // Do something
} else if (effectiveType === '4g') {
  // Do other things 
}
```

Is that possible? I found [NetworkInformation.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/type) read-only property, but it give me `undefined`. It does NOT support edge.

I saw that [EffectiveConnectionType enum](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#effectiveconnectiontype-enum) has no `wifi` value.

Environment:

- macOS 10.15.7
- Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.63

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`effectiveType` definition in the `NetworkInformation` API spec on W3C](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#effective-connection-types), `wifi` is not one of the "Effective Connection Types." The `EffectiveConnectionType` enum uses `4g` as its highest designation of a fast and reliable connection.

The `type` property on `navigator.connection` uses the [`ConnectionType` enum](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#connectiontype-enum) for its values, so `wifi` is one of its possible values. However, [only Chrome on Chrome OS supports the `type` field in the `NetworkInformation` API](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_networkinformation_type), so Edge will always say `type` is `undefined`.

If you're rolling a feature based on this technology in production, I would lean towards using `effectiveType`, but the `NetworkInformation` API is still an experimental technology that is [in unofficial draft](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/) and [not well supported across browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_networkinformation) .